# Consultando o tipo passado via método genérico

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
public List<TEntidade> MeuMetodo<TEntidade>()
{
      //My Code Here
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de eu pegar o tipo desta TEntidade?
O objetivo final é utilizar este Type para criar um switch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `typeof`. Depois, é só obter a `string` com o nome, e aplicar no switch, assim:

```
Type tipoEntidade = typeof(TEntidade);

string tipo = tipoEntidade.FullName;

switch (tipo)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o Typeof()
dessa forma:

```
Type seuTipo = typeof(TEntidade);
```